# All element of the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_m/I$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, quotient-group

Let $I = \lbrace \overline{0}, \overline{8}, \overline{16} \rbrace$ be an ideal in
$\mathbb{Z}_{24}$. Find all elements of quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_{24}/I$.

The answer is $\mathbb{Z}_{24}/I = \lbrace I, \overline{1} + I, \overline{2}+I, \dots, \overline{7} + I \rbrace$.
But, I still can't understand how to obtain it. Anyone can explain, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It results directly from the *Third isomorphism theorem*: $I$ is simply the quotient $\:8\mathbf Z/24\mathbf Z$, so
$$(\mathbf Z/24\mathbf Z)\big/I=(\mathbf Z/24\mathbf Z)\big/(8\mathbf Z/24\mathbf Z)\simeq \mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z.$$

Comment: Why it is $Z/24Z$ ?

Comment: and how can $I = 8Z/24Z$ ?

Comment: what if like this: $Z_{24} = \lbrace \overline{0}, \overline{1}, \dots, \overline{23} \rbrace$. Then, $Z_{24}/I = \lbrace \overline{0}+I, \overline{1}+I, \dots, \overline{7}+I \rbrace$ since for $\overline{8}$, it would be $\overline{8}+I = I+I = I$, for $\overline{9}: \overline{9} + I = \overline{1+8} + I = \overline{1} + I$, and so on.

Comment: Please answer my question Sir @Bernard

Comment: Sorry, I had not seen the above commentsYes, I think you can add these details. $I=8\mathbf Z/24\mathbf Z$ because $I$ is made up of the multiples of $8\bmod 24$ (since $4\cdot\bar 8=\bar 0$).

Comment: Oh, got it Sir. Thanks for explain! @Bernard

Comment: So, if I let $M = Z/Z_8$, then I can say that $M$ is made up of the multiples of $1 \bmod 8$, and hence $M = \lbrace \overline{0}, \overline{1}, \dots, \overline{7} \rbrace$, right?

Comment: But $\mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z$ is not a submodule of $\mathbf Z\;$!